# Компиляция шаблонов Vue.js на Rollup

Tags: vue.js, rollup

У меня есть файл `app.vue`, в нём код

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
    components: {
      "xxx": { template: `<div>hallow</div>`}
    }
}
</script>
```

Весь проект я собираю на `rollup`.

Шаблон самого `app.vue` отлично компилируется и работает. А вот inline шаблон `xxx` заранее не компилируется и компилируется только на лету. Поэтому если я использую только `runtime` сборку `vue` то выпадает с ошибкой что шаблон xxx не найден.

А почему этот шаблон не компилируется заранее, как это можно исправить?

Или это вообще не сделать? Или просто на rollup не делается?